# Send email using Logic apps using AD Service account

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Service account to send Email notifications using Logic Apps. The Service account has been configured with an email box and has been added to Office 365 tenant.

I am using the Consumption mode since Standard mode doesn't send Email notification via Office 365. I am using Outlook Office 365 connector available only in Consumption mode to send the alerts.

On using it , it gives me following error

> "Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox. This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or for accounts that are on a dedicated (on-premise) mail server. clientRequestId: 42886b20-eaec-490a-8124-6b4e4064ee13 serviceRequestId: a967a2ff-7244-d99b-7283-52f745fd78d6 More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '4B4754D7-D2D7-41C0-811D-FEF9F1244715'."

Any idea what might be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this due to lack of permissions for your mailbox account. This error usually occurs when the connector you used is connected with an account which is not of Office 365. One of the way to make this work is to [migrate mailbox data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/move-or-migrate-mailboxes/migrate-data-with-admin-center) from the current account to Office 365.

After migration to Microsoft 365 mailbox, I could able to send emails without any errors.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]